# Apache operation failed with code 1: dh key too small

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, openssl

I need to set a SSL DH key at 1024 bit on a website

I'm generating the key with

```
openssl dhparam -out /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem 1024
```

but when I restart apache, it returns the errore as in the title... I need to regenerate at 2048...

My versione of apache is 2.4.38

In the configuration file of Apache, there is

```
SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GC$
```

Is possibile to disable the check of DH key?

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround mentioned in the [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/ssl/ssl_faq.html#javadh).

You have to add the DHParam to the first certificate.

> To generate custom DH parameters, use the `openssl dhparam 1024`
>   command. Alternatively, you can use the following standard 1024-bit DH
>   parameters from RFC 2409, section 6.2:
>
> ```
> -----BEGIN DH PARAMETERS-----
> MIGHAoGBAP//////////yQ/aoiFowjTExmKLgNwc0SkCTgiKZ8x0Agu+pjsTmyJR
> Sgh5jjQE3e+VGbPNOkMbMCsKbfJfFDdP4TVtbVHCReSFtXZiXn7G9ExC6aY37WsL
> /1y29Aa37e44a/taiZ+lrp8kEXxLH+ZJKGZR7OZTgf//////////AgEC
> -----END DH PARAMETERS-----
> ```
>
> Add the custom parameters including the "BEGIN DH PARAMETERS" and "END
>   DH PARAMETERS" lines to the end of the first certificate file you have
>   configured using the `SSLCertificateFile` directive.